# Bash/ZSH - How to deal with filenames with spaces in a for loop (using [@])

Tags: arrays, zsh

I'm creating a zsh script that renames files selected in Path Finder on OSX. The script gets an array of paths through applescript. The array items are then processed in a for loop for renaming/moving.
The array output looks like:

```
'/Users/bwitime/Downloads/2017-05-17 at 12.08.jpeg', '/Users/bwitime/Downloads/Raspberry Pi - 5 Book Collection.pdf'
```

The script works, except when the filename contains spaces.
Here's the script:

```
read -A myFiles < <( /usr/bin/osascript  <<'EOS';
tell application "Path Finder"
    set finderSelection to {}
    set selectedItems to selection
    repeat with theItem in selectedItems
        set selFile to quoted form of (get POSIX path of (contents of theItem))
        copy selFile to the end of finderSelection
    end repeat
end tell

return finderSelection
EOS
)


for i in ${myFiles[@]}
do

    FILE=$(echo "$i" | sed 's:,::g' | sed s:"'"::g)
    DIR="${FILE:h}"
    FILENAME="${FILE:t}"
    FOLDERPREFIX="${FILE:h:t}"
    mv "$FILE" "$DIR/$FOLDERPREFIX-$FILENAME"
done
```

The $i returns as:

```
'/Users/bwitime/Downloads/2017-05-17
at
12.08.jpeg',
'/Users/bwitime/Downloads/Raspberry
Pi

5
Book
Collection.pdf'
```

I've already tried setting IFS='\n', but that doesn't work because there are no newlines between files in the array. Also, double quoting has no effect.

How to tackle this problem?

Comment: The AppleScript does not return an array; it returns a single string representation of the *elements* of an array. `read` doesn't consider the quotes to be syntactic.

Comment: Why not move the files in the AppleScript as well?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the internal field separator to ','

```
IFS=$',';
for i in ${myFiles[@]}
```

This seems to jump the spaces hurdle in bash.  Good luck!

Comment: Lots of files have ',' in their names(look at collections of MP3 files). One can also unset IFS, with `IFS=`

Comment: True, but that could be considered a separate question.   Perhaps it's best to add a step to modify the list of files created to use a set of characters that are probably not part of any file name, like "#|#" or such, then change IFS to look for that.